# How does one correctly avoid the avcodec_alloc_context3 leak from avformat_new_stream?

Tags: c, linux, ffmpeg

[This maddening thread](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.video.ffmpeg.devel/167998) describes the problem I'm having: a memory leak on shutdown due to some stuff allocated when `avformat_new_stream` is called.

Here's the valgrind stack trace from the leak:

- 1,447 (1,440 direct, 7 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 4
- at 0x4C2FFC6: memalign (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
- by 0x4C300D1: posix_memalign (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
- by 0x690DEFF: av_malloc ([mem.c:87](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/03eb0515c12637dbd20c2e3ca8503d7b47cf583a/libavutil/mem.c#L87))
- by 0x690E09D: av_mallocz ([mem.c:224](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/03eb0515c12637dbd20c2e3ca8503d7b47cf583a/libavutil/mem.c#L224))
- by 0x533D28A: init_context_defaults ([options.c:128](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/03eb0515c12637dbd20c2e3ca8503d7b47cf583a/libavcodec/options.c#L128))
- by 0x533D325: avcodec_alloc_context3 ([options.c:164](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/03eb0515c12637dbd20c2e3ca8503d7b47cf583a/libavcodec/options.c#L164))
- by 0x663D09E: avformat_new_stream ([utils.c:4384](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/03eb0515c12637dbd20c2e3ca8503d7b47cf583a/libavformat/utils.c#L4384))
- by 0x4204B6: main (test_ffmpeg.cpp:918)

So clearly the problem is that when a `AVFormatContext`'s stream's codec context's `priv_data` field is somehow not being freed.

My code frees the `AVFormatContext` with [`avformat_free_context`](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/03eb0515c12637dbd20c2e3ca8503d7b47cf583a/libavformat/utils.c#L4292). This calls [`ff_free_stream`](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/03eb0515c12637dbd20c2e3ca8503d7b47cf583a/libavformat/utils.c#L4284), which calls [`free_stream`](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/03eb0515c12637dbd20c2e3ca8503d7b47cf583a/libavformat/utils.c#L4234), which frees a few of the stream's codec context fields itself - but not the `priv_data` field!

Compared and contrast with [the corresponding code in `avcodec_close`](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/03eb0515c12637dbd20c2e3ca8503d7b47cf583a/libavcodec/utils.c#L1180).

The suggested solution to the problem from the thread: "close the codec firstly before calling `av_format_free_context`". Presumably this refers to calling `avcodec_free_context`? - but I'm already doing this! Roughly following the structure in [the muxing example](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/03eb0515c12637dbd20c2e3ca8503d7b47cf583a/doc/examples/muxing.c), I have an encoder context created by my code, that's used to track the uncompressed input data. Then there's another encoder context created internally by `avformat_new_stream` (as above), which is used internally by FFmpeg. I close the former, because it was opened using `avcodec_open2`, but I don't close the latter, because it wasn't. I am following the maddening thread's advice, and yet here I am.

Furthermore, reading between the lines, using `avcodec_free_context` to free the `AVStream`'s codec context is no good anyway, because when doing this (a) [`AVStream`'s `codec` field is deprecated](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/03eb0515c12637dbd20c2e3ca8503d7b47cf583a/libavformat/avformat.h#L892), so this gives a bunch of warnings, and (b) [there are no `NULL` checks in `free_stream`](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/03eb0515c12637dbd20c2e3ca8503d7b47cf583a/libavformat/utils.c#L4269), so this crashes at runtime.

What I have done for now is drag in the appropriate bit of code from `avcodec_close`, and put it in my own code just ahead of the call to `avformat_free_context`:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
#endif
    for(unsigned i=0;i<avf_context->nb_streams;++i) {
        AVStream *st=avf_context->streams[i];

        if(st->codec->priv_data&&
           st->codec->codec&&
           st->codec->codec->priv_class)
        {
            av_opt_free(st->codec->priv_data);
        }

        av_freep(&st->codec->priv_data);
    }
#ifdef __GNUC__
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
#endif
```

So that fixes the leak, and it's clearly (to my eyes) a bug, and I need to file a bug report or something.

However the [corresponding bug report](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/2937) is marked as fixed and closed... along with a link back to the maddening thread, and no further explanation. (This is why it is maddening!) So maybe I'm just using FFmpeg wrongly?

Can anybody confirm whether this is actually a bug in FFmpeg or not?

If it isn't a bug, what's the right sequence of calls to make?

(I'm using FFmpeg built locally from commit [03eb0515c12637dbd20c2e3ca8503d7b47cf583a](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/tree/03eb0515c12637dbd20c2e3ca8503d7b47cf583a). I had similar-looking problems with the one you get from the Ubuntu 16 package manager, which prompted me to build it myself with symbols and so on.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using libav API incorrectly. As part of API control mechanism each library has a `version.h` file (for example [`./libavformat/version.h`](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/libavformat_2version_8h_source.html)) that defines a set of macros controlling public API of that library.

```c++
typedef struct AVStream {
    int index;    /**< stream index in AVFormatContext */
    /**
     * Format-specific stream ID.
     * decoding: set by libavformat
     * encoding: set by the user, replaced by libavformat if left unset
     */
    int id;
#if FF_API_LAVF_AVCTX
    /**
     * @deprecated use the codecpar struct instead
     */
    attribute_deprecated
    AVCodecContext *codec;
#endif
    void *priv_data;

#if FF_API_LAVF_FRAC
    /**
     * @deprecated this field is unused
     */
    attribute_deprecated
    struct AVFrac pts;
#endif
```

When you encounter deprecation warnings you should look for corresponding API control macro and compile libav and your code that uses libav with this macro set to 0 (with `-DFF_API_LAVF_AVCTX=0` in case of `codec` field for example) overriding `version.h` content and ensuring that this deprecated API is not used anymore.

Comment: Thanks! - I know what the deprecation warning is for, and can guess what the ramifications of ignoring it might be ;) But if I take out the code that produces the deprecation warning, I get a memory leak. How do I fix the memory leak *without* this ugly workaround that I've had to come up with? That is my question.

Comment: After you turn this deprecated API off there will be no `st->codec` field and no code that initializes it and your additional cleanup code `av_opt_free(st->codec->priv_data);` will be unnecessary. Actually it looks like you are getting this leak _because_ you still have this deprecated stuff enabled. Typically devs don't really care about content of deprecated fields or correctness of deprecated methods. Suppressing deprecation warnings is wrong.

Comment: But it comes from the repo this way... so I guess this *is* a bug in FFmpeg then?

Comment: I would rather call this _API_ _deprecation_ _expenses_. Ideally it would be nice if old stuff got patched to work correctly, but who is going to update old stuff that shouldn't be used and that is going to be deleted soon anyway?

Comment: This assumes one can rebuild ffmpeg, how do you do when it's the version of e.g. a Linux distro which comes with all the toggles enabled?

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier I don't think it is possible to do anything in this case so you should just use ffmpeg as is, with all the toggles enabled, possibly adopting some workarounds in case if some problems pop up.